# Riemannian manifolds: every compact subset is contained in a connected relatively compact open subset

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, compactness, path-connected

While working on some problem (not relevant here), it turned out to be convenient to be able to enclose arbitrary compact subsets in "nicer" compact subsets, hence the question:

> if $(M,g)$ is a Riemannian manifold and $K \subseteq M$ is compact, does there exist a connected open subset $U \subseteq M$ such that $K \subseteq U$ and $\overline U$ is compact?

If $M$ is complete, then enclosing $K$ in a large enough ball will do, using the Hopf-Rinow theorem. If $M$ is not complete, then I have been able to construct either a relatively compact but not connected $U$, or a connected but not relatively compact one. Is it possible to get both properties?

Comment: What you ask for is a standard fact of manifold topology, which has nothing to do with Riemannian geometry. Voted to close. Incidentally, any  smooth manifold admits a complete Riemannian metric, e.g. because it can be smoothly embedded into a Euclidean space as a closed subset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to assume $K$ lies in a connected component of $M$.

Then for every point $x\in K$ there is a small open balls in $M$ whose closure is compact (you can just do this in charts). Since $K$ is compact it is covered by finitely many of such balls. Now choose a path that goes through these (finitely many) open balls.

Take an open subset $V$ containing this path whose closure is compact. Then define $U$ to be the union of $V$ with the finitely many open balls constructed before.

Comment: I myself had done only the first half of it, up to choosing that curve.